# Send a POST request from React Component to Spring Boot Controller

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, axios

So I have a React component called `UpdateJobComponent`. From here the user can either update a job or create a job (depending on the button they clicked in the previous component). The update of a job works fine however when I try to create a job i get the following errors:

**Errors**

> Put http://localhost:8080/jobs/-1 500
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
>       at createError

It tells me it's a PUT request and not a POST. However I thought I have it said up properly to match the the `createJob` PostMapping Controller. Below is the `UpdateJobComponent` code as well as the service files and also the Controller as well as the `JobDataService`.

I'm quite sure that the `updateJob` method in my JobController is receiving the POST and that's why I'm getting the problem but I can't figure out how to make the `createJob` in the JobController get it.

If you want to see anymore code just let me know, I tried to trim it as much as possible so not to take too long to look over! I'd really appreciate any help you can offer!

**UpdateJobComponent**

```
// imports

class UpdateJobComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        id: this.props.match.params.id,
        employer: this.props.match.employer,
        description: ''
      }
      // bind methods
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.id == -1) {
        console.log("Not mounting")
        return;
    }
    console.log(this.state.id)
    console.log("mounting")
    let userName = AuthenticationService.getLoggedUser()

    JobDataService.retrieveJob(userName, this.state.id)
    .then(response => this.setState({
        description: response.data.description,
        employer: response.data.employer,
        jobTitle: response.data.jobTitle
        }))
  }

  //    Error handling for form
  validate(values) {
    let errors = {} //  add validation for every field!!!!!!
    if (!values.description) {
        errors.description = 'Enter a description'
    } else if (values.description.length < 5) {
        errors.description = 'Description must be at least 5 characters long'
    }
    return errors
  }

  //    When save is clicked
  onSubmit(values) {
    // let employer = this.state.employer
    // let id = this.state.id
    // let jobTitle = this.state.jobTitle
    let job = {
        id: this.state.id,
        employer: values.employer,
        jobTitle: values.jobTitle,
        description: values.description
    }

    if (this.state.id === -1) {
        JobDataService.createJob(job)
            .then(() => this.props.history.push('/jobs'))
    } else {
        JobDataService.updateJob(job.jobTitle, job.employer, this.state.id, job)
            .then(() => this.props.history.push('/jobs'))
    }
  }

  render() {
    let { description, employer, jobTitle } = this.state
    return (
        <div>            
            <h3>Update {this.state.employer}'s {this.state.jobTitle} Job</h3>
            <div className="container">
                <Formik
                    initialValues={{description: description, employer: employer, jobTitle: jobTitle}}

                    onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                    validateOnChange={false}
                    validateOnBlur={false}
                    validate={this.validate}
                    enableReinitialize={true}    
                >
                {
                    (props) => (
                        <Form>
                            // Formik form, removed to make post smaller...

                                <div className="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
                                    <button className="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
                                </div>
```

**JobDataService**

```
// imports
const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8080'
const GET_ALL_JOBS_URL = `${API_URL}/jobs/`

    updateJob(jobTitle, employer, id, job) {
        return axios.put(`${GET_ALL_JOBS_URL}${id}`, job);
    }
    createJob(job) {
        return axios.post(`${GET_ALL_JOBS_URL}`, job);
    }
```

**JobController**

```
@Autowired
    private JobService jobService;

@PostMapping("/jobs/")
    public ResponseEntity<Job> createJob(@RequestBody Job job) {
        Job createdJob = jobService.createJob(job);
        java.net.URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(createdJob.getId())
                .toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }

    @PutMapping("/jobs/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Job> updateJob(@PathVariable long id, @RequestBody Job job) {
        job.setId(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(this.jobService.updateJob(job));
    }
// Other get and delete methods
```

**JobService**

```
public Job createJob(Job job) {
        if(job.getId() == -1 || job.getId() == 0) {
            job.setId(++idCounter);
            jobRepository.insert(job); 
        }
        return jobRepository.save(job);

    }

    public Job updateJob(Job job) {
        Optional < Job > jobDb = this.jobRepository.findById(job.getId());

        if (jobDb.isPresent()) {
            Job jobUpdate = jobDb.get();
            jobUpdate.setId(job.getId());
            jobUpdate.setEmployer(job.getEmployer());
            jobUpdate.setJobTitle(job.getJobTitle());
            jobUpdate.setDescription(job.getDescription());
            jobRepository.save(jobUpdate);
            return jobUpdate;
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Record not found with id : " + job.getId());
        }
    }
// Other methods
```

**Edit**
Full error message:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/jobs/-1 500
dispatchXhrRequest  @   1.chunk.js:561
xhrAdapter  @   1.chunk.js:411
dispatchRequest @   1.chunk.js:994
Promise.then (async)        
request @   1.chunk.js:807
Axios.<computed>    @   1.chunk.js:831
wrap    @   1.chunk.js:1308
updateJob   @   main.chunk.js:1428
onSubmit    @   main.chunk.js:955
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:4699
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:5014
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:4709
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:4705
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:5014
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:4750
(anonymous) @   1.chunk.js:5014
callCallback    @   1.chunk.js:16321
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   1.chunk.js:16370
invokeGuardedCallback   @   1.chunk.js:16423
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @   1.chunk.js:16438
executeDispatch @   1.chunk.js:16569
executeDispatchesInOrder    @   1.chunk.js:16594
executeDispatchesAndRelease @   1.chunk.js:16697
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @   1.chunk.js:16706
forEachAccumulated  @   1.chunk.js:16678
runEventsInBatch    @   1.chunk.js:16723
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @   1.chunk.js:16865
handleTopLevel  @   1.chunk.js:21818
batchedEventUpdates$1   @   1.chunk.js:40326
batchedEventUpdates @   1.chunk.js:17401
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem   @   1.chunk.js:21914
attemptToDispatchEvent  @   1.chunk.js:22031
dispatchEvent   @   1.chunk.js:21934
unstable_runWithPriority    @   1.chunk.js:51411
runWithPriority$2   @   1.chunk.js:28193
discreteUpdates$1   @   1.chunk.js:40343
discreteUpdates @   1.chunk.js:17426
dispatchDiscreteEvent   @   1.chunk.js:21901
```

Comment: "It tells me it's a PUT request and not a POST." What tells you this?

Comment: Hey, sorry should've specified. The console error on the browser

Comment: What is the exact error you get? Please [edit] your question to show this.

Comment: I've added a 'Errors' heading and copied in the two errors. I can take a screenshot of the console if you'd like!

Comment: And which line of code does that error refer to?

Comment: That's the problem! I can't get any info on the error, just that. I feel like it's being posted to the updateJob endpoints instead of the createJob endpoint.So it's getting trated as an update and then it's looking for a job in the database with that specific id which it obviously doesn't have.

Comment: The JavaScript console will show which line of code causes the error. It should be to the right side.

Comment: Yeah so when i extend the error it just prints a load of unhelpful technical terms. It doesn't specify a line in any file. When I click on the address "ttp://localhost:8080/jobs/-1" in the error it opens the 'Network' tab in the developer tools. This shows all the requests across my network. The one that pops up when I try to add a job confirms it's a PUT Request and it reads the error message from my updateJob method in JobService. I guess that's progress?? XD

Comment: So I know the problem is it's being treated as  PUT request instead of a POST. But I don't know why it's doing this or how to fix it.

Comment: The first step to figuring out why you get this error is to determine the code that causes the error. Please post the **entire** error message. You say it prints a "load of unhelpful technical terms". Perhaps I can help you decipher those terms so you can figure out what is going on here.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the bottom of the question!

Comment: "updateJob   @   main.chunk.js:1428
onSubmit    @   main.chunk.js:955" These two lines are the ones that matter. Unfortunately, it looks like the line numbers are from the transpiled webpack bundle rather than from your original source code. To fix the problem, I suggest adding `console.log()` statements to `onSubmit()` to determine why it calls `updateJob()` instead of `createJob()`.

Comment: Note that the Spring code just adds confusion. The problem is with the JS code that makes the request.

Answer (score 0):

I just added an if statement in the updateJob method to check if the id was -1. It's far from pretty and will need to be fixed again but wll do for now. Thanks for your time Code-Apprentice!

Comment: This is most likely a bandaid that covers a more serious problem. I suggest that you add `console.log()` statements or use your browser's development tools to debug `onSubmit()` to figure out why it calls `updateJob()` instead of `createJob()`. Most likely `this.state.id` isn't `-1` at the time of the `onSubmit()` call.